Query ignores Index Hint
I am running below query in Azure SQL DB:
SELECT 
    [TransactionID],
    [TrackingNumber],
    TRY_CAST([EventCode] as int) as EventCode,      
    [EventDesc] ,
    [EventTime],
    [EventCountry],  
    [EventState],
    [EventCity],
    [EventPostCode],
    [SpecialOperDesc],   
    [Reference]  
FROM [dbo].[MyTable]  
with (index = IX_EventTime_TrackNum_Reference)
WHERE   EventTime>= dateadd(d,-15,getdate()) 
        AND LEN(TrackingNumber) >= 22          
        AND Reference IS NOT NULL

Forcing it to use the nonclustered index IX_EventTime_TrackNum_Reference with Index Hint, and it worked until recently. The exec plan was nonclustered index seek plus lookups on clustered index.
Now it tries to use the ColumnStore Index Scan on existing nonclustered columnstore index. I can see it live using below:
 exec sp_WhoIsActive @get_plans = 2

Performance got worse, since nonclustered ColumnStore Index is considerably bigger in size than IX_EventTime_TrackNum_Reference, and it has some data in delta store. SQL DB is relatively small, and storage is slow.
What makes the query ignore Index hint ? And how to force it to use IX_EventTime_TrackNum_Reference again?

One way to reproduce the behaviour described in the question is to force the columnstore plan with a Plan Guide. Perhaps surprisingly, a Plan Guide with a showplan hint can force a plan that does not respect index hints.
db<>fiddle demo
Once a plan with the forced shape has been captured by Query Store, the plan can be forced there too. This forcing will survive the original plan guide being dropped, leaving you with a confusing situation where it's not at all clear how the hinted statement produced a plan not using that index.
There are a few other mechanisms that might result in an index hint being ignored, but I haven't verified those. Without an execution plan, you are much better placed than we are to investigate the cause. Suspects are mostly Query Store enabled, like Automatic Tuning, Plan Regression and Correction, CE feedback hints, and possibly QS hints (though I can't immediately think of a mechanism using that).

not sure if this matters, but columnstore index is nonclustered which includes all columns. And table has clustered rowstore index on ID column. But anyway, query store doesn't even have this plan with columnstore index scan for this query, reporting application kept timing out after 2 hours of running this query. Query store has plan with seek+lookup, and I tried to force it there, but no effect. Solved this by dropping noncl. columnstore index, and query got back to seek+lookup and  5 mins of execution total. Thank you in any case, that was very informative! trying to reach Socratic someday

Being nonclustered doesn't matter, no. Bit of a mystery then. Most of your comment makes more sense as an answer btw. I don't mind about the green check. Glad you found my guesses of general interest.
